# userinfo.getuseremail() returns noreply@salesforce.com in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have created a package in salesforce that will make an http callout request with user's email id to get data for that email and add the data to some custom object. But when I tried using `UserInfo.getUserEmail()` as a request parameter but it makes a request with `noreply@salesforce.com`. It does work when I run it on the dev account. I also tried using

```
1.String userName = UserInfo.getUserName();
2.User activeUser = [Select Email From User where Username = : userName limit 1];
3.String userEmail = activeUser.Email;
```

But line no 2 gave me an error saying `List has no rows for assignment to SObject`

This is my first salesforce package, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not really sure if its related, but might want to take a look at https://success.salesforce.com/questionDetail?qId=0873000000079P1AAI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10413/userinfo-getuseremail-returns-noreplysalesforce-com-in-salesforce

This was the problem. Daniel answered it well.
For whoever is having same-similar problem, It happens because scheduled jobs are run on their server as 'phantom' processes. So we have to provide it with the installedid when using installhandler or creating schedules. It wont have any knowledge of user otherwise. Save the installedid somehow!

Answer (score 0):

```
List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

is returned when no rows are found. This won't fix the problem but best practice is to assign it to a list like

```
List<User> activeUsers = [Select Email From User where Username = : userName];
if(activeUsers.size() > 0)
  User activeUser = activeUsers[0];
```

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices

To fix your issue, it's possible that the profiles between the two times you're running the query are different with different permissions assigned. If you're not set to read permission on the user object you would get such an error.